# How do you print out values (Strings) in a Map without the [...] and , separators?

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm printing out string values stored in a map but I don't want it printing the [] or , separator characters. How Do I print only the values?

```
Iterator<String> iterator = styles.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator.next().toString();
    String value = styles.get(key).toString();
    stylePlaceHolder = value + "\n";
}
siteElements.add(stylePlaceHolder);

Iterator<String> iterator2 = libraries.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
    String key = iterator2.next().toString();
    String value = libraries.get(key).toString();
    libPlaceHolder = value + "\n";
    System.out.println(libraries.values().toString());
}
```

generates:

```
03-23 17:56:56.350: I/System.out(9642143): [<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
03-23 17:56:56.350: I/System.out(9642143): 
, <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.
min.css" />

03-23 17:56:56.350: I/System.out(9642143): , <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
03-23 17:56:56.350: I/System.out(9642143): 
]
```

Comment: You can loop much more efficently over a map using the `entrySet` method to loop over entryies. You can even use an enhanced for loop - `for(final Entry<String, Thing> entry : myMap.entrySet())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you care to print out only the values of `styles`, don't bother with the `keySet`.  Since you are constructing your stylePlaceHolder in a loop, use `StringBuilder`, not `String` concatenation. And, your loops are throwing away each value when it gets another one.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for(String style: styles.valueSet()) {
    b.append(style).append("\n");
}
siteElements.add(b.toString());
```

Do nearly the same with `libraries`. In fact, extract most of the above to a method:

```
private String values(Map<?, ?> map) {
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    for(Object value: map.valueSet()) {
        b.append(value).append("\n");
        // append can take an Object; it calls toString on it.
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

For faster work, consider Google Guava and its `Joiner` class instead. Remember--no one is paying you to write code. You're paid to solve problems.

```
private String values(Map<?, ?> map) {
    return Joiner.on("\n").join(map.valueSet()) + "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **toString() version of the HashMap or any map class creates a string with [] in them.** So you cannot help it. Best thing you can do is to iterate over the map and print the values on your own  in the way you want them.

Same is the case if you try to print the any collection in java like List,Set or Map.

Eg :

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(10);
    list.add(20);

    System.out.println(list);

    // Output is : [10, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are relying on the `toString` method of something without overriding it. You haven't told us what the `value` part of your map is.

You may need to override the `toString` method of your object or, if that object is another `Collection`, you may need to loop over that too:

```
    final Map<String, Collection<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(final Entry<String, Collection<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        for(final String value : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println(value);                
        }
    }
```

Note that you can use an enhanced for loop to iterate over a `Map` much more efficiently than by looping over keys and calling `get` for each one.

Answer (score 1):

No love for regex?

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");
    map.put("key3", "value3");
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
    System.out.println(map.keySet().toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", ""));
    System.out.println(map.values().toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\],]", ""));
```

output:

```
[key3, key2, key1]
key3 key2 key1
value3 value2 value1
```

Comment: `map.put("[what,about]", "[th,is?]");`

Comment: Fair enough, but it's not meant to be a general solution so much as one tailored to the data at hand. Just cause: .toString().replaceAll("^\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]$", "").replaceAll(", ", " ")); (getting a little silly now)